# Why does Spark fail with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to implement a Hadoop Map/Reduce job that worked fine before in Spark. The Spark app definition is the following:

```
val data = spark.textFile(file, 2).cache()
val result = data
  .map(//some pre-processing)
  .map(docWeightPar => (docWeightPar(0),docWeightPar(1))))
  .flatMap(line => MyFunctions.combine(line))
  .reduceByKey( _ + _)
```

Where `MyFunctions.combine` is

```
def combine(tuples: Array[(String, String)]): IndexedSeq[(String,Double)] =
  for (i <- 0 to tuples.length - 2;
       j <- 1 to tuples.length - 1
  ) yield (toKey(tuples(i)._1,tuples(j)._1),tuples(i)._2.toDouble * tuples(j)._2.toDouble)
```

The `combine` function produces lots of map keys if the list used for input is big and this is where the exceptions is thrown.

In the Hadoop Map Reduce setting I didn't have problems because this is the point where the `combine` function yields was the point Hadoop wrote the map pairs to disk. Spark seems to keep all in memory until it explodes with a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`.

I am probably doing something really basic wrong but I couldn't find any pointers on how to come forward from this, I would like to know how I can avoid this. Since I am a total noob at Scala and Spark I am not sure if the problem is from one or from the other, or both. I am currently trying to run this program in my own laptop, and it works for inputs where the length of the `tuples` array is not very long.

Comment: is "data" already an RDD?

Comment: I just edited the code to show how I load the data.

Comment: OK i went ahead and answered having already assumed it were in fact (as you show) an RDD

Comment: It would be nice to see the ultimate solution included at the end of your post, thanks!

Comment: The ultimate solution is the one I marked with the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adjusting the memory is probably a good way to go, as has already been suggested, because this is an expensive operation that scales in an ugly way. But maybe some code changes will help.

You could take a different approach in your combine function that avoids `if` statements by using the `combinations` function. I'd also convert the second element of the tuples to doubles before the combination operation:

```
tuples.

    // Convert to doubles only once
    map{ x=>
        (x._1, x._2.toDouble)
    }.

    // Take all pairwise combinations. Though this function
    // will not give self-pairs, which it looks like you might need
    combinations(2).

    // Your operation
    map{ x=>
        (toKey(x{0}._1, x{1}._1), x{0}._2*x{1}._2)
    }
```

This will give an iterator, which you can use downstream or, if you want, convert to list (or something) with `toList`.

Comment: Hi @ohruunuruus, I think the sliding does not provide the same behaviour of what I want to do. The `toKey` function simply combines the two strings.

Comment: Hmm alright. I'll have to take a look when I've got access to a spark-shell. Regardless, you might explore other ways of performing the combine operation.

Comment: Hi @ohruunuruus, that did the trick, I think returning the iterator is what actually does the trick because my for loop tries to assemble a huge array in memory and it fails with out of memory. I knew my `for` loop didn't look very scala-like but I started learning yesterday so that was what I could do. thanks for the time!

Answer (score 18):

Add the following JVM arg when you launch `spark-shell` or `spark-submit`:

```
-Dspark.executor.memory=6g
```

You may also consider to explicitly set the number of workers when you create an instance of `SparkContext`:

### Distributed Cluster

Set the slave names in the `conf/slaves`:

```
val sc = new SparkContext("master", "MyApp")
```

Comment: The memory option does not help unfortunately. I still get the Out of Memory exception.

Comment: After I added this option and changing the minimum partitions to 100 `spark.textFile(conceptsFile, 100).cache()` it seems to run a lot longer but ends up dyeing with a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Comment: If you change the spark.executor.memory=12g does it run even longer? How much memory do you have on the systems to allocate to the workers? You might want to add more workers - in the conf/slaves file - as well.

Comment: hi @javadba it looks like it was actually the fact that I was trying to assemble the whole permutation array in memory that was killing it. Making the `combine` function return an iterator seemed to do the trick. Thanks for the time though!

Comment: About use with Spark Shell 2.2, I added `-Dspark.executor.memory=6g`, "error: Invalid literal number" on "6g". Running script by `sshell -i script.scala`

Answer (score 17):

In the documentation (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html) you can read how to configure the executors and the memory limit.
For example:

```
--master yarn-cluster --num-executors 10 --executor-cores 3 --executor-memory 4g --driver-memory 5g  --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=409
```

The memoryOverhead should be the 10% of the executor memory.

Edit: Fixed 4096 to 409 (Comment below refers to this)

Comment: Shouldn't 10% of 4G be around 410(M)?

Comment: Yes, it should be around 10%, sorry. So: spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=409

Comment: The configuration key 'spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead' has been deprecated as of Spark 2.3 and may be removed in the future. Please use the new key 'spark.executor.memoryOverhead' instead.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue during long regression fit. I cached the train and test set. It solved my problem.

```
train_df, test_df = df3.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2], seed=142)
pipeline_model = pipeline_object.fit(train_df)
```

pipeline_model line was giving `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`
But when I used

```
train_df, test_df = df3.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2], seed=142)
train_df.cache()
test_df.cache()
pipeline_model = pipeline_object.fit(train_df)
```

It worked.

Answer (score 2):

This JVM garbage collection error happened reproducibly in my case when I increased the `spark.memory.fraction` to values greater than 0.6 . So it is better to leave the value at it's default value to avoid JVM garbage collection errors. This is also recommended by https://forums.databricks.com/questions/2202/javalangoutofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceede.html .

For more information one why `0.6` is the best value for `spark.memory.fraction` see  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15796 .