# Getting OutofMemoryError- GC overhead limit exceed in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

in the middle of project  i am getting  bellow error after invoking a function in my spark sql query
[image: exception pic]

i have written a user define function which will take two string and concat them after concatenation  it will take right most substring length of 5 depend on total string length(alternate method of right(string,integer) of sql server )

```
  from pyspark.sql.types import*


def concatstring(xstring, ystring):
            newvalstring = xstring+ystring
            print newvalstring
            if(len(newvalstring)==6):
                stringvalue=newvalstring[1:6]
                return stringvalue
            if(len(newvalstring)==7):
                stringvalue1=newvalstring[2:7]
                return stringvalue1
            else:
                return '99999'


spark.udf.register ('rightconcat', lambda x,y:concatstring(x,y), StringType())
```

it works fine individually. now when i pass it in my spark sql query as column this exception occured
the query is

[image]

the written query is

```
spark.sql("select d.BldgID,d.LeaseID,d.SuiteID,coalesce(BLDG.BLDGNAME,('select EmptyDefault from EmptyDefault')) as LeaseBldgName,coalesce(l.OCCPNAME,('select EmptyDefault from EmptyDefault'))as LeaseOccupantName, coalesce(l.DBA, ('select EmptyDefault from EmptyDefault')) as LeaseDBA, coalesce(l.CONTNAME, ('select EmptyDefault from EmptyDefault')) as LeaseContact,coalesce(l.PHONENO1, '')as LeasePhone1,coalesce(l.PHONENO2, '')as LeasePhone2,coalesce(l.NAME, '') as LeaseName,coalesce(l.ADDRESS, '') as LeaseAddress1,coalesce(l.ADDRESS2,'') as LeaseAddress2,coalesce(l.CITY, '')as LeaseCity, coalesce(l.STATE, ('select EmptyDefault from EmptyDefault'))as LeaseState,coalesce(l.ZIPCODE, '')as LeaseZip, coalesce(l.ATTENT, '') as LeaseAttention,coalesce(l.TTYPID, ('select EmptyDefault from EmptyDefault'))as LeaseTenantType,coalesce(TTYP.TTYPNAME, ('select EmptyDefault from EmptyDefault'))as LeaseTenantTypeName,l.OCCPSTAT as LeaseCurrentOccupancyStatus,l.EXECDATE as LeaseExecDate, l.RENTSTRT as LeaseRentStartDate,l.OCCUPNCY as LeaseOccupancyDate,l.BEGINDATE as LeaseBeginDate,l.EXPIR as LeaseExpiryDate,l.VACATE as LeaseVacateDate,coalesce(l.STORECAT, (select EmptyDefault from EmptyDefault)) as LeaseStoreCategory ,rightconcat('00000',cast(coalesce(SCAT.SORTSEQ,99999) as string)) as LeaseStoreCategorySortID from Dim_CMLease_primer d join LEAS l on l.BLDGID=d.BldgID and l.LEASID=d.LeaseID left outer join SUIT on SUIT.BLDGID=l.BLDGID and SUIT.SUITID=l.SUITID left outer join BLDG on BLDG.BLDGID= l.BLDGID left outer join SCAT on SCAT.STORCAT=l.STORECAT left outer join TTYP on TTYP.TTYPID = l.TTYPID").show()
```

i have uploaded the the query and after query state here. 
how could i  solve this problem. Kindly guide me

Comment: Make sure your `spark.memory.fraction=0.6` . If it is higher than that you run into garbage collection errors, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47283211/179014

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest thing to try would be increasing spark executor memory:
    `spark.executor.memory=6g`
Make sure you're using all the available memory. You can check that in UI.

**UPDATE 1**

`--conf spark.executor.extrajavaoptions="Option"` you can pass `-Xmx1024m` as an option.

What's your current `spark.driver.memory` and `spark.executor.memory`?
Increasing them should resolve the problem.

Bear in mind that according to spark documentation:

> Note that it is illegal to set Spark properties or heap size settings with this option. Spark properties should be set using a SparkConf object or the spark-defaults.conf file used with the spark-submit script. Heap size settings can be set with spark.executor.memory.

**UPDATE 2**

As GC overhead error is garbage collcection problem would also recommend to read this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1393503/7231644)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i have just tried it out. but nothing changes 
ubuntu@tvnubtest:~/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7$ bin/pyspark --conf executor.extraClassPath=$SPARK_HOME/lib/sqljdbc4.jar --driver-class-path $SPARK_HOME/lib/sqljdbc4.jar --jars $SPARK_HOME/lib/sqljdbc4.jar --executor-memory 6g

Comment: Try allowing your JVM more Java heap space by:
`java -Xmx1024m com.yourName.yourClass`

Comment: If your objects are consuming too much memory, it will allow JVM to run smoothly

Comment: could i write above config code like  passing parameter in spark which i have posted previous comment thread or do i need extra house keeping  for that. i am newbie in spark so i am slightly confused. sorry for asking silly question

Comment: However I'd focus on 3 parameters:  
`spark.driver.memory=45g`  
`spark.executor.memory=6g`  
`spark.dirver.maxResultSize=8g`  
It's just an example of my config that sorted similar problem out. Play with your config, but before check how much available memory you have in UI.

Comment: thanks for your reply , I have increased  the physical memory in 16G. the problem solved temporarily though. but  getting Overhead again. I guess your java-Xmx1024m code will be needed now. I am using pyspark and loading the existing table using jdbc driver in Linux pc. could you say which class I need to focus I mean com.yourname,yourclass  since I didn't create any class . sorry for bothering you much :(

Comment: `--conf spark.executor.extrajavaoptions="Option"`  
you can pass `-Xmx1024m` as an option.  
Bear in mind that according to spark documentation:  

>Note that it is illegal to set Spark properties or heap size settings with >this option. Spark properties should be set using a SparkConf object or >the spark-defaults.conf file used with the spark-submit script. Heap >size settings can be set with spark.executor.memory.  
  
What's your current `spark.driver.memory` and `spark.executor.memory`?

Comment: sorry, can't edit the above comment  
`--conf spark.executor.extrajavaoptions="Option"` you can pass `-Xmx1024m` as an option.  
What's your current spark.driver.memory and spark.executor.memory?  
Bear in mind that according to spark documentation:  
>Note that it is illegal to set Spark properties or heap size settings with this option. Spark properties should be set using a SparkConf object or the spark-defaults.conf file used with the spark-submit script. Heap size settings can be set with spark.executor.memory.

Comment: well i have done some tweak here . i have increased  PC memory   to 32G and have set driver memory to 24G and  executor memory to 8G right now.and it worked for now  i guess. i am not getting exception .and currently trying to  increase java heapsize for avoiding trouble in future.Thank you very much for your details reply jarek for now. but might  knock you if i am getting odd exception again  :P kidding