# SPARK SQL java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, mysql, sql, apache-spark

I try to fetch the data for one day to test and create a temp table using Spark SQL. After that, I am performing my queries on temp table. So that process can be fast but still getting GC memory issue.

Spark configuration:

```
sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[1]").setAppName("Scheduler"); 
sparkConf.set("spark.driver.memory", "2g") ; 
sparkConf.set("spark.executor.memory", "1g"); 
sparkConf.set("spark.memory.onHeap.size","1g") ; 
sparkConf.set("spark.num.executors", "4"); 
sparkConf.set("spark.executor.cores", "1"); 
sparkConf.set("spark.serializer", KryoSerializer.class.getName());
```

Comment: Thank you jrook, for correcting

Comment: Just curious, where did you get config `spark.memory.onHeap.size` from?

Answer (score 0):

OoM can happen also when the GC activity consumes a certain percentage of CPU resource. I would try to increase the heap and/or  use a profiling tool  jconsole or visualvm to check what is the root cause

Comment: Thank you for your reply, did check my spark configuration. Is it fine?

Comment: please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462061/why-does-spark-fail-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded

Comment: I would also check your code you execute - it might not be efficient